# Android - How to run a signed APK in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have signed my Android app (via the `Export...` option), but how can I then run that apk (i.e., rather than the unsigned apk) on my device via Eclipse?

Comment: You can directly install the signed apk in device then why your using via eclipse?

Comment: when you run with eclipse it will take unsigned apk from bin folder if you want to run your signed apk then copy the apk to device then install or you can use the adb tool

Comment: no, u can copy apk in device and install apk

Comment: you can use command prompt? adb install (yourapkfilepath)